# Помощь с выводом на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Дело в том, что в **.gTable** много классов **.forum** и когда я вывожу это так:

```
var forum_name = $(this).find('.forum').text()+'|';
```

то получается, что все классы сливаются в один и в самом конце ставится |. Скриншот -

[image: img]

*Вопросы о ВКонтакте* и *Обсуждение программ и сервисов* выглядят на самом деле так:

```
<div class="forum">
 Вопросы о ВКонтакте
</div>

<div class="forum">
 Обсуждение программ и сервисов
</div>
```

На деле должно выводиться так:

Вопросы о ВКонтакте|Обсуждение программ и сервисов|

Мой говнокод с этим не справился, помогите, пожалуйста сделать правильно:

```
 $('.gTable:last').hide();
 $('.gTable').each(function() {
  var cat_name = $(this).find('.gTableTop').text();
  var forum_name = $(this).find('.forum').text()+'|';
  $(this).html('\
  <div class="forum_cat_name">'+cat_name+'</div>\
  <div class="forum_themes_content">\
   '+forum_name+'\
  </div>\
  ');
 });
```

Comment: Так:  

    
    var $forums= $('.forum');
    var forum_name= [];
    for (var i=0; i<$forums.length; i++) {
        forum_name.push( $forums[i].innerHTML.trim() );
    }
    forum_name = forum_name.join('|');

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, а если я захочу в div обернуть? Придётся перепиливать? И желательно бы готовое решение в мой код сунуть :/

Comment: Если захотите обернуть в div, то просто сделайте:  

    var $forums= $('.forum div');

Comment: Вы не поняли. Вот так:

<div class="test">'+$(this).find('.forum').text()+'</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nsnQg/

**UPD**: версия улучшенная пользователем [IVsevolod](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11360/ivsevolod):
http://jsfiddle.net/Zsp63/

Comment: p#forum-list WAT?

Comment: Параграф с ID "forum-list", куда выводим результат. Можно заменить на что-угодно, например на div.

Comment: только я думаю незачем постоянно получать текст, объединять со старым текстом и присваивать текст. Лучше так:

    $('.gTable > .forum').each(function() {
        $('p#forum-list').append($(this).text()+' | ');    
    });

имхо, так быстрее и красивее будет. Да и $('p#forum-list') можно вынести в переменную за each

Comment: IVsevolod, Вы правы, так лучше.